# virtualenv fails on digital ocean's ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04

I'm depoying a django app on digital ocean's ubuntu server 18.04 via SSH and is encountering an error:

> The path python2 (from --python=python2) does not exist

These are the steps I already did and it came from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-django-and-set-up-a-development-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04

```
*** System restart required ***
Last login: Fri Sep 27 10:02:52 2019 from 112.207.104.140
root@pw-proj-apc:~# sudo apt-get install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
root@pw-proj-apc:~# python3 -V
Python 3.6.8
root@pw-proj-apc:~# sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
root@pw-proj-apc:~# pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
root@pw-proj-apc:~# pip3 install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/lib/python3/dist- 
packages
root@pw-proj-apc:~# virtualenv --version
15.1.0
root@pw-proj-apc:~# cd myproject
root@pw-proj-apc:~/myproject# virtualenv env
The path python2 (from --python=python2) does not exist
root@pw-proj-apc:~/myproject#
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Check /usr/bin, whether there is python2 symlink pointing to latest python 2, if not you can create a symlink or use --python=python2.7 if python2.7 is the latest one available

Comment: @Alasdair I edited my question and added the steps I did

Comment: I've been using virtualenv env on my local machine for installing virtualenv. Does it require python3 -m venv env on digital oceans ubuntu server?

Comment: You can use `virtualenv -p python3`, but you should switch to using `python3 -m venv`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell virtualenv to use Python 3 with `virtualenv -p python3 env`.

However, you don't have to install `virtualenv` at all. Since Python 3.5, the recommended way to create a virtualenv is:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

The advantage of using `python3 -m venv` is that it uses the same python as `python3` does.

Answer (score 0):

First, use which python to see where your python binary is, so you can execute and verify which version of python the system is using.

But, I can bet that --python=python will set to python2

Comment: Okay. I did which python but it didn't return anything. Is installing python on digital oceans ubuntu the same as installing python on a mac?

Comment: `which python` didn't return anything because Python 2 isn't installed on that server. You shouldn't install Python 2, because you want a Python 3 virtualenv.